# Consulta agrupada 2 tablas en oracle 8 ( no tengo INNER )

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo 2 Tablas :

Tabla1 : Cabeceras
Aqui guardo la cabecera de cada comprobante de venta 
campos : ID(clave unica),SUBTOTAL (numerico 10,2),IVA (numerico 10,2), TOTAL (numerico 10,2).

Tabla2 : DETALLE
Aqui guardo las filas de cada comprobante de venta,que puede ser una o varias. Tambien hay un campo llamado TIPO que segun su valor refiere a si esa fila es un ítem del comprobante ( valor 1 ) o un impuesto especial ( valor 15 ).

El problema que tengo es que en DETALLE hay varios comprobantes que tienen ese impuesto especial, por lo cual tienen mas de 1 fila. Al correr la siguiente consulta me suma el campo TOTAL de la tabla CABECERAS tantas veces como filas hay de ese mismo comprobante en DETALLE.
Mi necesidad es que me tome el campo TOTAL 1 sola vez y que solo me traiga los registros que en la tabla DETALLE tienen el campo TIPO=15

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL)AS SubTotal,SUM(a.IVA)AS IVA,SUM(a.TOTAL)AS TOTAL,SUM(b.IMPORTE) AS IMPUESTO
FROM CABECERAS a, DETALLE b 
WHERE a.FECHA_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/07/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND a.PUESTO=123  
AND (a.NRO_SERIE >= 10500 AND a.NRO_SERIE <= 10550)
AND a.ID=b.ID(+)
AND b.TIPO=15
GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.ID)
```

[image: Ejemplo de la salida de esta consulta]

En la gráfica se puede apreciar que la ultima fila ID 33200615 da un total de 520 , cuando en realidad es 260 , lo sumarizó 2 veces porque en la tabla DETALLE este comprobante tiene 2 filas , aunque lo único que me interesa obtener de la tabla DETALLE es el valor del campo IMPORTE que alli se ve en la columna IMPUESTO.
Tener en cuenta que es Oracle 8i por lo cual no funciona INNER JOIN !

Comment: Un detalle dijiste que el total es de 260, pero tu subtotal da 243.54 tampoco esta bien no?. Porque si le sumas tu iva que es 51.14 da 294.68 mucho mas que tu total gravado

Comment: Si , es verdad, no lo había notado , tambien me duplicó el subtotal .que es 121.77 y el iva que es 25.57 , solo me tomó correctamente el impuesto

Comment: SELECT a.ID, a.SUBTOTAL AS SubTotal, a.IVA AS IVA, a.TOTAL AS TOTAL, sum(b.IMPORTE) AS IMPUESTO y lo has probado asi?

Comment: Ahi me genera 4 filas por cada ID y no me da las sumatorias

Comment: una solucion fea seria sum(a.SUBTOTAL / COUNT(A.SUBTOTAL))

Comment: Es "LA SOLUCION" !!!! Gracias !!!

Comment: como valoro tu respuesta ? no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa seria

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL / COUNT(a.SUBTOTAL))AS SubTotal,
             SUM(a.IVA / COUNT(a.IVA))AS IVA,
             SUM(a.TOTAL / COUNT(a.TOTAL))AS TOTAL,
             SUM(b.IMPORTE) AS IMPUESTO
FROM CABECERAS a, DETALLE b 
WHERE a.FECHA_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/07/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND a.PUESTO=123  
AND (a.NRO_SERIE >= 10500 AND a.NRO_SERIE <= 10550)
AND a.ID=b.ID(+)
AND b.TIPO=15
GROUP BY ROLLUP (a.ID)
```